# How to click Dropdown list

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

```
<div id="ab100">
    <iframe width="1000" height="600" src="...">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" action=".." method="post">
        <select id="abl03" style="..">..\',\'\')', 0)" name="l03ue">
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><Select a Value></option>
                <option value="1">AB</option>
                <option value="2">AD</option>
                <option value="3">BC</option>
                <option value="4">CA</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

When I want to click on DDL, I normally do this:

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'ab103').select('CA')
```

and it will select the option value = "4".  But I am getting this error:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:id=>
"abl03", :tag_name=>"select"}
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in `assert_exists'
```

Maybe this problem is due to its in a iframe.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 'Select' tag.  Modified it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. There is no opening <select> tag in your example.  I'm assuming `<div id="abl03">` should be `<select id="abl03">` or that it's simply missing.
2. The id for `<select id="abl03">` is `abl03`, but id locator value in `select_list(:id => 'ab103')` is `ab103`.
3. `<Select a Value>` in `<option value="0" selected="selected"><Select a Value></option>` should be `&lt;Select a Value&gt;`.

So, the `unable to locate element`error is valid because a <select> tag with the specified id does not exist.

If you run into issues with frames, check out http://watirwebdriver.com/frames/ and https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/frame_spec.rb for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I seen a similar question like this on stackoverflow.  Sorry for posting it again.  Thanks.

```
browser.frame(:index => 0).select_list(:id => ab103).select(/CA/)
```

any other suggestions are welcome too.  Thanks.